# Letter-spacing bug: Webkit browsers ignore letter-spacing less than 1px

Tags: letter-spacing

Webkit browsers like Chrome and Safari ignore letter-spacing less than 1px (or 0.1em) while Firefox displays 0.1px steps just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/d5y6n/2/

Is there a possibility to make Webkit browsers recognize letter-spacing less than 1px?

CSS

```
.spacing-1 {
    letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="spacing-1">This is some text …</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a way to make css letter-spacing: 0.5 px?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7811225/1456376).