# letter-spacing less than one pixel

Tags: css

I have got a little problem with a spacing. I want to have spacing less than 1 pixel. Here is my html

```
<div id="head">
     <h1>Mira's</h1>
    <br>
     <h2>Koding place</h2>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Museo;
    src: url("fonts/Museo300-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
}
body {
    background-color: black;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family:'Museo', 'Lucida Console', Courier;
    font-size: 7em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #029408, 0 0 70px #029408, 0 0 80px #029408, 0 0 100px #029408, 0 0 150px #029408;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.65em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Museo', 'Lucida Console', Courier;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -1.65em;
    margin-left: 0.13em;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

Problem is that it's not letter spacing less than one `px`, is there any *hack* to make it less than one px?

Here is jsfiddle with it http://jsfiddle.net/3np3y/

Also dont mind that some things in CSS are `px` and some are `em`. I will retype everything to `em` soon.

Comment: Maybe this can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811225/is-there-a-way-to-make-css-letter-spacing-0-5-px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letter spacing can have negative value, so try that :)

I.E. `letter-spacing: -4px;`

Comment: Maybe my English is bad so I have not undestand what OP wants, but he asked for letter spacing less than one px?

Comment: Why did your answer got downvotes? It seems working in my code http://jsfiddle.net/3np3y/1/ . Is there anything bad on making 'letter-spacing' negative?

Comment: If this is an accepted answer, then the question meant something very different from what it says.

Comment: Well -8px is lesser than one pixel. So?

Comment: From question I figure out that OP doesn't know about negative letter spacing, and he tryied to get value between 0 and 1 px. So I've pointed out that letter spacing can be negative also. And -4<1, so... :)

Comment: Keep in mind that negative values are often used with `margin` and the results are predictable among browsers.  There is some discussion (search 'css negative letter spacing') about the topic on various forums and blogs.  Keep in mind that some browsers handle letter-spacing differently.  For example, see the discussion by: http://blarg.aaronpropst.com/IE-CSS-does-letter-spacing-stupidly